# nft (!token) list reports [invalid type] but returns no cli error

Tags: nftables

I entered:

> sudo nft 'insert rule inet firewalld filter_INPUT
> meta l4proto  {tcp,udp} ct state related,established ct original proto-dst 53 counter packets 0 accept

But *nft list* says:

> meta l4proto { udp,tcp} ct state established, related ct original proto-dst 0x35 [invalid type] counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept

What is the parameter driving this invalid type?
Suggestions for a better dns packet examining rules welcome. But I have other evidence that this parser is not up to par.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can't reproduce your error (using nftables 1.0.7). You should always mention the kernel version and the nftables version when talking about a bug or a misbehaving feature, and verify in advance that upgrading to a newer versions fixes (or not) the problem.

Comment: Fedora 38. rpm says nftables sys 1.0.5-2.

Comment: OK.  It doesn't show on fedora 39 rawhide. Kernel 6.4

Comment: Do you know any good nft tutorials ? I have gone thir wiki. Access.redhat.com, wiki.nftables.org, https://pablotron.org/articles/nftables-examples/

Comment: You already mentioned wiki.nftables.org, I don't know any more doc.